# Is it appropriate to add a new reference in revising a manuscript?

Tags: academic-writing, scientific-publishing

Is it appropriate to add a new reference in the revised version of a manuscript?

Comment: Can you be more explicit?  What kind of manuscript? What kind of revision? Why do you want to add this reference?

Comment: @Ted Wrigley, Scientific manuscript, double blind revision, it helps to answer the reviewers' comments.

Comment: So this is for reviewers on a manuscript submitted (but not yet accepted) for publication? Then yes, adding a new reference is completely normal and acceptable. Review periods are meant to allow you to make minor revisions to the text at the suggestion of reviewers, if you so chose. If the new reference improves the quality of the manuscript, feel free...

Comment: Yes this is, thank you

Comment: If you added content that you need to reference, or if you had *neglected* to cite something previously, and you need to correct that omission, then adding a reference would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would say that it is recommended to do so when you add a statement that you can support with a citation to other academic work.

This is often the case with the revised parts of the manuscript that address the reviewers' comments.

Less common, yet still acceptable, is to add a reference to recent work that was published while your manuscript was under revision. Needless to say that the reference is meant as a support to a statement in your manuscript, and that it should be pertinent.